# UICollectionView swift 3 laggy scroll UIImage

Tags: swift, swift3, uiimage, native, collectionview

I am experiencing very choppy scrolling in my collection view. There are only 10 cells. It is because of my method of retrieving the images which is to take the URL and turn it to UIImage data.

Images variable is just an array of image URLs.

```
    public func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return images.count
    }

    public func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "mediaCells", for: indexPath) as! MediaCell
    let url = URL(string: images[indexPath.row] as! String)
    let data = try? Data(contentsOf: url!)
    cell.mediaImage.image = UIImage(data: data!)
    return cell
    }
```

A solution I found was to do this first for all images. The problem with this approach is that it will have to wait for all images to download the data and append to the array before we display the collectionView. This can take quite a few seconds 10-15 seconds before we can render the collection. Too slow!

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    Alamofire.request(URL(string: "myURL")!,
        method: .get)
        .responseJSON(completionHandler: {(response) -> Void in
            if let value = response.result.value{
                let json = JSON(value).arrayValue
                for item in json{
                    let url = URL(string: item["image"].string!)
                    let data = try? Data(contentsOf: url!)
                    self.images.append(data)
                }
                self.collectionView.reloadData()
        }
    })
    }
```

Comment: You are downloading the images synchronously, try to do it async. There are few third party libraries to make it easy.

Comment: Thanks. I followed your recommendation and got it working well.

Answer (score 0):

Used SDWebImage from cocoapods to do Async image fetching.

https://cocoapods.org/?q=SDWebImage

```
cell.mediaImage.sd_setImage(with: URL(string: images[indexPath.row] as! String))
```

Answer (score 0):

Some will shout about the use of globals, but this is the way I did previously:

**Declare a global array of UIImage**

```
var images: [UIImage] = []
```

**When image is downloaded, append it to that array**

```
for item in json{
        let url = URL(string: item["image"].string!)
        let data = try? Data(contentsOf: url!)
        let image = UIImage(data: data!)
        images.append(image)
        NotificationCenter.default.post(Notification.Name(rawValue: "gotImage"), nil)
}
```

**Follow the Notification in your VC**

```
override function viewDidLoad() {
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(collectionView.reloadData()), name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "gotImage"), object: nil)
    super.viewDidLoad()
}
```

**Do not assign an image if not available in your cell for collectionView**

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
     .....
     if let image = images[indexPath].row {
          cell.mediaImage.image = image
     }
     ....
}
```

PS: If all the downloading and loading action happens in the same VC, just declare `images` inside your VC class.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you need to do the lazy loading of images in your collection view based on the visible cells only. I have implemented the same approach like this.

**1) First steps you need to create a class named it as PendingOperations.swift**

```
class PendingOperations {
 lazy var downloadsInProgress = [IndexPath: Operation]()
 lazy var downloadQueue: OperationQueue = {
 var queue = OperationQueue()
 queue.name = "downloadQueue"
 queue.maxConcurrentOperationCount = 1
 return queue
 }()
}
```

**2) Seconds steps create a class named it as ImageDownloader where you can make your network call to download the image.**

```
class ImageDownloader: Operation {
 let imageId: String
 init(imageId: String) {
  self.imageId = imageId
 }
 override func main() {
  if self.isCancelled {
   return
  }
 Alamofire.request(URL(string: "myURL")!,
        method: .get)
        .responseJSON(completionHandler: {(response) -> Void in
            if let value = response.result.value{
                let json = JSON(value).arrayValue
                for item in json{
                    let url = URL(string: item["image"].string!)
                    self.image = try? Data(contentsOf: url!)
 })
 if self.isCancelled {
   return
     }
  }
}
```

**3) Third steps implement some methods inside viewController to manipulate the operations based on the visible cells.**

```
func startDownload(_ image: imageId, indexPath: IndexPath) {
 if let _ = pendingOperations.downloadsInProgress[indexPath] {
    return
 }
 let downloader = ImageDownloader(image: imageId)
 downloader.completionBlock = {
  if downloader.isCancelled {
   return
   }
}
 pendingOperations.downloadsInProgress.removeValue(forKey: indexPath)
 pendingOperations.downloadsInProgress[indexPath] = downloader
 pendingOperations.downloadQueue.addOperation(downloader)
 }
}

func suspendAllOperation() {
 pendingOperations.downloadQueue.isSuspended = true
}

func resumeAllOperation() {
  pendingOperations.downloadQueue.isSuspended = false
}

func loadImages() {
 let pathArray = collectionView.indexPathsForVisibleItems
 let allPendingOperations = 
 Set(Array(pendingOperations.downloadsInProgress.keys))
 let visiblePath = Set(pathArray!)
 var cancelOperation = allPendingOperations
 cancelOperation.subtract(visiblePath)
 var startOperation = visiblePath
 startOperation.subtract(allPendingOperations)
for indexpath in cancelOperation {
    if let pendingDownload = 
 pendingOperations.downloadsInProgress[indexpath] {
 pendingDownload.cancel()
}
 pendingOperations.downloadsInProgress.removeValue(forKey: indexpath)
}
 for indexpath in startOperation {
    let indexPath = indexpath
    startDownload(imageId, indexPath: indexPath)
}
}
```

**4) Fourth steps to implement the scrollView delegate methods.**

```
func scrollViewWillBeginDragging(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
        suspendAllOperation()
    }

func scrollViewDidEndDecelerating(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    loadImages()
    resumeAllOperation()
}

func scrollViewDidEndDragging(_ scrollView: UIScrollView, willDecelerate decelerate: Bool) {
    if !decelerate {
        loadImages()
        resumeAllOperation()
    }
}

func clearImageDownloaderOperations() {
    if pendingOperations.downloadsInProgress.count > 0 {
        pendingOperations.downloadsInProgress.removeAll()
        pendingOperations.downloadQueue.cancelAllOperations()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Kingfisher 5 for prefetching, loading, showing and caching images we can solve the issue.

```
let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: path)
let provider = LocalFileImageDataProvider(fileURL: url)
imageView.kf.setImage(with: provider)
```

https://github.com/onevcat/Kingfisher/wiki/Cheat-Sheet#image-from-local-file